# How to handle promise rejection in this case

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In here i want to add new field in collection User (User.facebook.botLink)
but i get an error.
Code where i get error looks like this:

```
 app.post('/savelink/', async (req, res, next) => {
        try{

            console.log("================USER FACEBOOK ===============" + user.local.email)
            const {link} = req.body;
            console.log(link);

            User.update(
            {email: user.facebook.email}, 
            {botLink : link},
            {multi:true}, 
                function(err, numberAffected){  
            });

            res.status(200).send(link);

        }
        catch(e){
            next(error);
        }


    });
```

**Error i'm getting:**

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: error is not defined
(node:6032) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: This code is a wild mix of callback style vs. promise/async (+ missing await). Also you use the undeclared variable `error` as the message states. Take some time to read up on the basics about asynchronism and error handling.

Comment: You probably meant `e` instead of `error` in your exception handler.

Comment: Change `catch(e) { next(error); }` to `catch(e) { next(e); }`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 catch(e){
            next(error);
        }
```

to

```
catch(e){
            next(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aslo do a ***try/catch...finally***.
Note that the ***finally*** block will be executed regardles of the result of **try/catch**.
For more einformation, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

```
try{
 // some code
}
catch(error){
// handle error
}
finally {
  // do something else
}
```